# Trying to create a Tobit model

Tags: r, regression

I'm looking to create a model where my outcome variable is positive and continuous - number of conversions from Facebook ads.

Here's a sample of the data. "Results_Total" is the outcome variable -

```
| Team            | Opp_Team             | Channel_Market | Week | Thuuz_Rating | Team_EloRating | Opp_Team_EloRating | Divisional | Spend   | Results_Total |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| Atlanta Falcons | Tampa Bay Buccaneers | Fox_In         | 1    | 46           | 1486           | 1412               | 1          | 4681.63 | 48      |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| Atlanta Falcons | Carolina Panthers    | Fox_In         | 4    | 68           | 1510           | 1604               | 1          | 5373.1  | 45      |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| Atlanta Falcons | Denver Broncos       | Fox_In         | 5    | 66           | 1541           | 1690               | 0          | 5339.04 | 15      |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| Atlanta Falcons | Seattle Seahawks     | Fox_In         | 6    | 68           | 1576           | 1654               | 0          | 6304.21 | 41      |
```

I have installed the AER package and tried this code:

```
library(AER)
nfltobit = tobit(Results_Total ~ Team + Opp_Team + Channel_Market + Week + Spend + Team:Spend + Opp_Team:Spend + Channel_Market:Spend + Week:Spend, left = 0 , right = Inf, data = nfltrain)
```

For some reason I get an error:

> unused arguments (left = 0, right = Inf, data = nfltrain)

Perhaps I'm not approaching this correctly, or the tobit function isn't the correct method. Any ideas?

Comment: There are other R packages with a `tobit` function as well (e.g. [VGAM](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VGAM/versions/1.0-4/topics/tobit)). Try specifying your function as `nfltobit = AER::tobit(...)` instead?

Comment: Hi @Z.Lin thanks for the help. When I tried this, it went through. However, when I followed up with the summary(nfltobit) command, it said:"Error in solve.default(vcov.hyp) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0"